# Displaying the user name in a Gigya form

Tags: gigya

The Gigya [documentation](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/UI+Builder+Template) mention (at part *Display a Field Value*) that in a **label**, it is possible to use double curly brackets and a field from the Schema to display it.
Like `Hi, {{profile.firstName}}!`

That is the theory, but it doesn't work for me. I see the value of `profile.firstName` in the console but this double curly bracket thing just isn't converted to the value.
Any idea how can it be debugged or solve this?

**Update:**
I try to use this feature on the Profile Update screen after the user is logged in. And calling `accounts.getAccountInfo`, I get the profile and the firstName has value as well.

**Update (29/11/2019):**
Thanks for the help, @Levi! Finally, I found the missing part: `data-binding="true"` should be added to the `label` or `h2` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the limited information, it is difficult to tell, however, a couple things to note are that the profile object is only available for logged in users, so this will only work on Profile Update type screens. Also, you must have RaaS enabled on your account. Finally, this only works for fully registered users, if you are using a lite user login token, the profile fields are also not available. Other than that, if there is a test page I can take a look or you can open a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am definitely using this for the Profile Update screen after the user is logged in. And calling the `accounts.getAccountInfo` function, I get the profile and the firstName has value as well. (I will add this details to my question)

Comment: Btw, I can't open a support ticket because Gigya is part of SAP and now they moved they support to SAP Launchpad and it seems a bit difficult to open a support ticket there.

Comment: Something else you can try, is this will only work for newer screen-sets, so, if you are trying to use this functionality on screen-sets that existed before this support was added, it won't work. If you are using older screen-sets, you can just create a new collection and see if it solves the issue. Other than that, I will see if I can determine if anything else might be causing the problem.

Comment: Thank, this is a new screen-sets. I tried with two "types" of new screen-sets, built with the UI Builder and with a custom built one as well. Neither works.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this yet. If you would like, you can go to the Documentation page (https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/UI+Builder) and all the way at the bottom of the page, you can review the page by selecting a Star Rating, and then leave a comment. These comments are not public until approved internally. If you put your API key in the message body of the review, I can check out your specific case; otherwise, I am afraid you might have to try and open a proper ticket.

Comment: Hi @Levi, unfortunately, my Gigya account is very limited, I can log in into the Gigya console, but I can't log in to the documentation page. So, I can't rate it.

Comment: And I can't open a ticket either. I try to send PM via Twitter if it feasible.

Comment: You can rate the page using any social network account, i.e., Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: I tried it. Facebook doesn't work because the connection is not secure, Twitter also refused to use the site and finally for Google, the site requests rights to delete contacts and account info completely and I will not allow it.

So, I created a new screen sets as you mentioned that a new one should work. And it does. I removed every unnecessary field and added one new label which now is able to display the `{{profile.firstName}}`. Then I opened the Advanced Customisation but it doesn't contain any curly bracket or `firstName` text. Strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184391/discussion-between-tomh-and-levi).